# upgrade oracle apex 19.1 to 19.2 on centOS

Tags: oracle-apex

maybe someone knows what the problem is, I had an apex 19.1 (expanded on a centos ), I decided to upgrade to 19.2. I was following this link https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/upgrading-to-latest-AE-release.html#GUID-4B4A2BDC-11AA-4ACF- 88B2-E320D6361596 . But there was a problem. Almost immediately after @ apexins.sql, the disconnect from the oracle
I use XE18. Even before updating to the new version, I deleted the apex folder with apex 19.1 and instead unzip the apex folder with 19.2

[image]

Comment: Have you retried the upgrade? What have you deleted?

Comment: @ThomasStrub look, I have all the files in the folder, opt, there was already an api folder, I deleted it, and unzip a new one from 19.2, went into it, then ran into the database, and entered the command "@ apexins.sql APEX APEX TEMP / i / "and got this error
(I have never updated my apex before)

Comment: Did you have a tablespace named APEX? Why do you have spaces before and after the i in `/ i /`?

Comment: @DanMcGhan When I expanded into apex on 19.1, the first teams were
"- CREATE TABLESPACE apex DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/XE/XEPDB1/apex01.dbf' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M;
- @ apexins.sql APEX APEX TEMP / i / "

Comment: Have you verified that the tablespace was created correctly? Again, why do you have spaces before an after the i in `/ i /` (the forth parameter you're passing to the script)? Finally, have you checked for an install log file? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmig/reviewing-log-of-installation-session.html#GUID-E6FF6A64-5F6D-42AE-81CC-8BEB3F989551